# How to copy row into datatable and save to localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm in the final steps to finish my project.

and maybe this is the last question to discuss this my project.
**But I have some obstacles:**

> 1. I want to copy row from `table1` to `table2` and save the result row in the `table2` into localStorage.
> 2. I have no idea to copy row from mainTable[`table1`] to `table2` then save it to localStorage like my input form method ( JSFiddle 1 ).

I already successfully create **Save row table from input form**
and *store to localStorage* and i want the *Copy row* working like this *Create Row Feature*, can saved into localStorage.

```
var dataSet;
try {
  dataSet = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataSet')) || [];
} catch (err) {
  dataSet = [];
}
$('#myTable').dataTable({
  "data": [],
  "columns": [{
    "title": "First Name"
  }, {
    "title": "Last Name"
  }, {
    "title": "Action"
  }],
  "bStateSave": true,
  "stateSave": true,
  "bPaginate": false,
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "bFilter": false,
  "bInfo": false,
  "bAutoWidth": false
});
oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();
for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
  oTable.row.add(dataSet[i]).draw();
}

$('#Save').click(function() {
    var data = [
      $('#first').val(),
      $('#last').val(),
      "<button class='delete'>Delete</button>"
    ];
    oTable.row.add(data).draw();
    dataSet.push(data);
    localStorage.setItem('dataSet', JSON.stringify(dataSet));

});
```

[**JSFiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/czta34ak/) : *Create row and Save to localStorage*

**[JSFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/tcp8vvnh/)** : *Copy Row and Save row to localStorage* **[I'm Working here]**

anyone can helps me?

If you think I'm lazy. I appreciate that because I have not been too able to make a function and this is my new thing in programming. but I always look for references, and to solidify it, I need to come here.

Correct me if im wrong with this question.

Comment: In the exmaple 1 you are already doing that...can you elaborate a little more!

Comment: in the example 2, i want  the copied row can saved into localStorage like example 1.

Comment: but, i dont know how to save the copied row to localStorage

Comment: So you want to replicate the behaviour of example 1 in example 2, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like the working example. In `copyRows` function push copied rows to `dataSet` array and then save the array to `localStorage`. And set data of `table2` to `dataSet`. Also read saved `dataSet` from `localStorage` initially.

**UPDATE:**
You have to use different `localStorage` item for different table. Here I use `dataSet_tableid` format to save data in `localStorage`.

Here is the modified `JS`.

```
var mainTable = $('#table1').dataTable({
    "bStateSave": true,
    "stateSave": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false
});

/*SELECT OPTION */
mainTable.on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

$('#copyToTable2,#copyToTable3').on('click', function () {
    let $elem = $(this);
    var table = $("#table" + $elem.attr('id').replace(/[a-zA-Z]/ig, ''));
    var tbl_id = table.attr('id');

    var $row = mainTable.find(".selected");
    if (!$row.length) {
        console.log('You must select some rows to copy first');
        return;
    } else {
        var r = confirm("Copy to table " + tbl_id + "?");
        var table_to_copy = table.dataTable();
        if (r == true) {
            copyRows(mainTable, table_to_copy);
            console.log("Copied!");
            setTimeout('console.clear()', 2000);
        }
    }
});

/* FROM HERE SAVE ROW ================*/

function copyRows(fromTable, toTable) {
    var $row = fromTable.find(".selected"),
      storageName = 'dataSet_' + toTable.attr('id'), //added this line 
      dataSet = localStorage.getItem(storageName) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName)) : []; //added this line 

    $.each($row, function (k, v) {
        if (this !== null) {
            addRow = fromTable.fnGetData(this);
            toTable.fnAddData(addRow);
            dataSet.push(addRow); //added this line 
        }
    });

    localStorage.setItem(storageName, JSON.stringify(dataSet)); //added this line 
}

/* =============== TABLE 2 ================== */

$('#table2').dataTable({
    "data": localStorage.getItem('dataSet_table2') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataSet_table2')) : [], //changed here
    "columns": [{
        "title": "First Name"
    }, {
        "title": "Last Name"
    }, {
        "title": "Action"
    }],
    "bStateSave": true,
    "stateSave": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false
});

$('#table3').dataTable({
    "data": localStorage.getItem('dataSet_table3') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataSet_table3')) : [], //changed here
    "columns": [{
        "title": "First Name"
    }, {
        "title": "Last Name"
    }, {
        "title": "Action"
    }],
    "bStateSave": true,
    "stateSave": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tcp8vvnh/6/)**

Comment: This is so cool. but can you help me? i got another problem, when i have another table, dataSet will be showing in all table, not just selected table. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/tcp8vvnh/4/)

Comment: i can use it when i want adding new table? i will adding much of tabel.

Comment: Yes you can @CalvinAnanda